# Multi value parameters SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssas, ssas-2012

I have 2 parameters `@ProductID` and `@Customer`.
`@ProductID` and has `Product1_ID` has customer Say `Cust1` and `Product2_ID` has same Customer `Cust1`.

When cascaded using MDX in SSRS report to select all available values for Customer for each ProductID's it shows two values in the cascaded drop down list for `Cust1` but selects only the first `Cust1` (which points to `Product1_ID`).

Is there a way in which I can get the report to select all values even when two ID's have same Customers in MDX.

I set available values and default values using dataset which has `ProductID`, Customer filterd on `ProductID`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround to resolve this issue.

http://blog.westmonroepartners.com/manipulating-ssrs-parameter-functionality/#comment-565971

Answer (score 0):

Found something similar to this

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c24a881f-f22c-481a-91d3-d4b1082f2f78/parameter-change-does-not-refresh-default-values-of-dependent-parameters?forum=sqlreportingservices

Looks like there is no direct way to handle the situation. Please let me know in case anyone has any other workaround or solution